# min-max standardization for the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do min-max standardization for the data which is in the local variable **x_vals** which i converted into the **dataframe**

```
x_value =  pd.DataFrame(data=x_vals)
```

which has

> [506 rows x 1 columns]

sample data is mentioned below

```
                                                     0
0    [0.00632, 2.31, 6.575, 65.2, 4.09, 296.0, 396....
1    [0.02731, 7.07, 6.421, 78.9, 4.9671, 242.0, 39...
2    [0.02729, 7.07, 7.185, 61.1, 4.9671, 242.0, 39...
3    [0.03237, 2.18, 6.998, 45.8, 6.0622, 222.0, 39...
4    [0.06905, 2.18, 7.147, 54.2, 6.0622, 222.0, 39...
5    [0.02985, 2.18, 6.43, 58.7, 6.0622, 222.0, 394...
6    [0.08829, 7.87, 6.012, 66.6, 5.5605, 311.0, 39...
7    [0.14455, 7.87, 6.172, 96.1, 5.9505, 311.0, 39...
8    [0.21124, 7.87, 5.631, 100.0, 6.0821, 311.0, 3...
9    [0.17004, 7.87, 6.004, 85.9, 6.5921, 311.0, 38...
10   [0.22489, 7.87, 6.377, 94.3, 6.3467, 311.0, 39...
```

and to convert into standardization format i did

```
  scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
  scaler = scaler.fit(x_value.values)
  print(scaler)
```

and it shows the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "knn.py", line 33, in 
>       scaler = scaler.fit(x_value.values)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 308, in fit
>       return self.partial_fit(X, y)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 334, in partial_fit
>       estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 433, in check_array
>       array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
>   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

how to standardizer the data ? 
Thanks!

Comment: This is a numpy object array of lists, not an array of arrays. Please do something about that first.

Comment: Do you have pandas? If you do, you can just pass this data into a dataframe and that'll be handled for you. Afterwards, standardisation should be simple.

Comment: great idea thanks @COLDSPEED

Comment: When  i changed to dataframe and intend to saw the dtype i get the following error **ValueError: failed to cast to 'float64' (Exception was: setting an array element with a sequence.)**

Comment: If your data is in a CSV file, try using `pd.read_csv` to read it.

Comment: no no.. my data is not in csv .. Its stored locally

Comment: Err, I don't know why you get that error, I don't have access to your data or environment. You could either edit your question or open a new one with enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: okay i'll edit this question ..

Comment: The data is stored as lists in one column, do something like `scaler.fit(np.array(df[0].values.tolist()))`